# How i can make my own DOS(Disk Operating System) distribution?

Tags: operating-systems, batch-file, ms-dos, freedos

So, i am making a batch file OS project in Windows, and i want to make it run under DOS. I want to make my own custom distribution of DOS that i can use as a shell of my project. I tried to find a clean source code, but no avail. How i can do it?

Comment: The very first google result for freedos is http://www.freedos.org/ and the source code is available there. In what ways is this not sufficient?

Comment: How i can customize it? I mean, change the name, add some commands to system?

Comment: you can customioze DOS but don't call it your own distribution. We don't use such nonsense terminology in MS/DOS/Windows land.  http://superuser.com/questions/908915/can-i-make-a-dosbox-like-in-virtual-box. Notice that I got the game Xenon 2 running, if you scroll down my answer to that question, you see a pic.

Comment: The source code for MSDOS 1.1 and 2.0 are freely available [here](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/microsoft-ms-dos-early-source-code/).

Comment: It seems to me that you don't really want to create a full DOS (Disk Operating System), but maybe you just want to create your own custom user interface in a dos window/command prompt. Is that the case? Just curious..

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Like Windows 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org) has source code available.

Comment: ...Missed it. (embarrased)

Comment: How i can customize it?

Comment: Look for [compilation instructions](http://zet.aluzina.org/index.php/Compiling_FreeDOS)